# Rails form post randomly corrupted using unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm running my app called Mockaroo on http://ec2-54-245-163-172.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com on unicorn in production. About 1 out of every 10 times a user clicks the "Download" button on the main page, the post parameters aren't correctly converted into the params hash passed to the controller, which in this case leads to certain required params not being present.  I can tell this is the case based on the debug output displayed in the error page.  When the error occurs, the params has looks something like:

```
{"mns_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"min_date"=>"2/28/2012"}},
 "schema"=>{"columns_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"max_date"=>"3/1/2013",
 "date_format"=>"%-m/%-d/%Y",
 "values"=>"",
 "min_words"=>"10",
 "max_words"=>"20",
 "min_paragraphs"=>"1",
 "max_paragraphs"=>"3", ...
```

when it should actually look like

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"LAV7Olx38E2UH64CS6BWpIT1qiHigcwfF780250iHkE=",
 "schema"=>{"columns_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"id",
 "forgery_type"=>"Popular.row_number",
 "position"=>"1",
 "min"=>"1",
 "max"=>"100",
 "decimal_places"=>"2",
 "min_date"=>"2/28/2012",
 "max_date"=>"2/28/2013", ...
```

It's almost like it's dropping the first part of the post body.  This doesn't happen when I run thin in development.  Note that I'm running unicorn on port 80 directly, not behind another web server like nginx or apache.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  If you want to try it yourself, you'll know you got the error when you see the following message:

```
NoMethodError in DataController#generate

undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

The most bizarre part is that it only occurs in webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari, but never in Firefox. Has anyone run into anything like this.  Are there any suggestions for how to debug this further?

-- Update --

It's worth noting that I installed the same app on another server using passenger and apache and this error does not occur - so it must be something specific to unicorn.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. I wonder if it's some rack layer gem that's causing the issue. It wil be interesting for us compare our gemfiles.